# Trying to solve a limit without Taylor series [don't put on hold]

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits

For instance in my recent post:

I have this limit to find $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\cdots+\left(-1\right)^{n-1}\cdot \frac{1}{2n-1}\right)=\text{ ?}$$

and we know too this integral $$I_n=\int _0^1\:\frac{x^n}{x^2+1}dx$$ and that relation for recurrence: $$I_{2n}\:\cdot \:\left(-1\right)^{n-1}\:=\:\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{2n-1}-\:\left(-1\right)^{n-1}\cdot I_{2n-2}$$

Okay and now how we can continue, if we know recurrence relation because my teacher adviced me to use this and I don't know what helps me, because if I put value for n>2, I'll find some terms and I need to find the sums...

okay so tell me someone if that recurrence relation can helps me and if not put on hold...

Comment: Maybe you can use [the elementary proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Leibniz's_Formula_for_Pi).

Comment: what helps me a recurrence relation if I find it? that I want to know... my teacher advised me to find a recurrence relation ! why? because I have sum and if I find a recurrence relation just will know some terms not all and not sum of them, and is not help... just I think, maybe I am wrong...

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland That was my first impulse too, but OP wants to avoid using Taylor series, and all three of the proofs at the link use the Taylor series of $\arctan x$ at $0$.

Comment: Can you use integration?

Comment: I will try, I comeback with result

Comment: $I_{2n}=\int _0^1\frac{x^{2n}\:}{x^2+1}dx=\frac{1}{2n-1}-I_{2n-2}=\int _0^1\:\frac{x^{2n-2}}{x^2+1}dx$  okay,  now how we can continue? please some help guys...

Comment: Let $$S_{n} = 1 - \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + (-1)^{n - 1}\frac{1}{2n - 1}$$ and we add your original recurrence relations for $n = 1, 2, \ldots, n$ we get $(-1)^{n - 1}I_{2n} = S_{n} - I_{0} = S_{n} - (\pi/4)$. To evaluate limit of $S_{n}$ just show that $I_{2n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. This is easily seen if we note that $$0 \leq I_{2n} = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2n}}{1 + x^{2}}\,dx \leq \int_{0}^{1}x^{2n}\,dx = \frac{1}{2n + 1}$$ and apply Squeeze theorem.

Comment: and we show $I_{2n}\:=\:0\:$ to prove that Sn = pi/4?

Comment: $S_{n}$ is just the expression whose limit you want to find out. Now we use your recurrence relation and put $n = 1, 2, 3,\ldots$ in that to get \begin{align} I_{2} &= 1 - I_{0}\notag\\ -I_{4} &= -\frac{1}{3} + I_{2}\notag\\ I_{6} &= \frac{1}{5} - I_{4}\notag\\ \cdots &= \cdots\notag\\ (-1)^{n - 1}I_{2n} &= (-1)^{n - 1}\frac{1}{2n - 1} - (-1)^{n - 1}I_{2n - 2}\notag\end{align} If you add these equations you will note all $I_{2}, I_{4}$ etc cancel from left and right of equation and only term with $I_{2n}$ remains and we get $$(-1)^{n - 1}I_{2n} = S_{n} - I_{0}$$

Comment: And yeah you do need to show that $I_{2n} \to 0$ for the limit of $S_{n}$  to be $I_{0} = \pi/4$. I have shown in my previous comment how to prove $I_{2n} \to 0$.

Comment: and we demonstrate $I_{2n}\:->\:0\:$ to prove that $S_n\:=\:\frac{\pi }{4}$

Comment: I wish it was possible to format my comments as answer. But anyway you can read the comments one by one and let me know if you have any further doubt.

Comment: Thank you very much Paramanand, you are an awesome man, thank you again, you don't know how I feel now because you make me understand... I can't give you +1 respect...God bless you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Not sure if this is the method your teacher is looking for. Probably not...)

You're looking for the infinite sum:$\renewcommand{\d}[1]{\operatorname{d}\!{#1}}$
$$1-\frac13+\frac15-\frac17+\dotsb$$

> Now, note that:
>   $$\int_0^1t^{n-1}\d t=\left[\frac{t^n}n\right]_0^1=\frac1n$$
>   This is central to how I'm going to solve this problem. In particular, letting $n=0,2,4,$ etc., this gives us the family of equalities: $\int_0^1\d t=1,\int_0^1t^2\d t=\frac13,\int_0^1t^4\d t=\frac15,$ etc.

Thus, we have:
\begin{align}
1-\frac13+\frac15-\frac17+\dotsb&=\int_0^1\d t-\int_0^1t^2\d t+\int_0^1t^4\d t-\dotsb\\
&=\int_0^1(1-t^2+t^4-\dotsb)\d t
\end{align}
You may recognize $1-t^2+t^4-\dotsb$ as a geometric series. (If you forgot: $1+u+u^2+\dotsb=\dfrac1{1-u}$.) Here we have $u=-t^2$, so we have:

> $$1-t^2+t^4-\dotsb=\frac1{1+t^2}$$

Continuing, we have:
\begin{align}
1-\frac13+\frac15-\frac17+\dotsb&=\int_0^1(1-t^2+t^4-\dotsb)\d t\\
&=\int_0^1\frac1{1+t^2}\d t\\
&=\left[\arctan t\right]_0^1\\
&=\arctan1-\arctan0\\
&=\frac\pi4-0\\
&=\frac\pi4
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, I know that method... but we need to use with that recurrence relation who I found some minutes ago

Comment: @Lucas Considering the fact that the sum is $\dfrac\pi4$... I really have no idea.

Comment: @Lucas Well, I guess you can prove that $1-\dfrac12+\dotsb\dfrac1{2n+1}=\int_0^1\dfrac{1+t^n}{1+t^2}$, inductively, and then take the limit to get $\int_0^1\dfrac1{1+t^2}=\dfrac\pi4$.

Comment: Who see my post please some help, because I don't understand why my teacher advised me to use this recurrence relation ... for what?

Comment: columbus8myhw I can prove that, this was my first intuition too because I think is only method, maybe I will find new reviews later from other users, think so...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use the fact that the series:
$\displaystyle 1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+...+\left(-1\right)^{n-1}\cdot \frac{1}{2n-1}$ 

is actually taylor series expansion of $tan^{-1}(x)$ at $x= 1$.

The function $tan^{-1}(x)$ satisfies the differential equation

$\displaystyle (x^{2}+1)\frac{d^2y(x)}{dx^2}+ 2x\frac{dy(x)}{dx} = 0$

with $y(0)=0, y^{'}(0)=1$.
 Finding a recurrence for taylor coefficients $u(n)$ of $y(x)$ must solve your case now.

From initial conditions of differential equations, we can say $u(0) = 0, u(1) = 1$.
Replacing $y(x)$ by $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty u(n) x^{n}$ in the differential equation, we get 
$\displaystyle2x\sum_{n=1}^\infty nu(n) x^{n-1} + (x^2+1)\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)u(n) x^{n-2} = 0$.
By collecting powers of $x^n$ and shifting summation indices, 
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty (2n + n(n-1))u(n) x^{n}+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)(n+2)u(n+2) x^{n} = 0$

By comparing coefficients of $x^n$, we get this recurrence relation for $n \ge 0$:
$\displaystyle (n^2 + n)u(n) + (n^2 + 3n + 2)u(n+2) = 0 $
Cancelling $(n+1)$ we get, $nu(n) + (n+2)u(n+2) = 0$ .

So the recurrence relation must be
 $nu(n) + (n+2)u(n+2) = 0$ 
with $u(0) = 0, u(1) = 1$.